# Java ComboBoxes dependent on another combobox

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I have an `ArrayList` of objects that I have used to populate a `ComboBox` (Managers) as shown below:

```
testingPeople people = new testingPeople();
people.loadPeople();
ArrayList<Person> testing = new ArrayList<Person>();
testing = people.getManagerList();
for (int i=0; i < testing.size(); i++) {
    jComboBox1.addItem(testing.get(i));
}
```

Now, I want to populate the second `ComboBox` (subordinates) based on the values selected in the 1st `ComboBox`. In the event handler, I have tried the following:

```
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Insert Name here")) {
    jComboBox2.addItem("it works!");
}
```

And, other variations but I'm still drawing a blank.

Can someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code corresponding to populating `jComboBox2` in the item listener of `jComboBox1`. For example,

```
ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        String item = (String) evt.getItem();
        switch (item) {
            case "Item 1":
                jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
                jComboBox2.addItem("A");
                jComboBox2.addItem("B");
                jComboBox2.addItem("C");
                break;
            case "Item 2":
                jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
                jComboBox2.addItem("E");
                jComboBox2.addItem("F");
                jComboBox2.addItem("G");
                break;
        }
    }
};
jComboBox1.addItemListener(itemListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

the action event for combo box takes place when a combobox's value changes so your code should work in the event handler of the first combobox